# Hide after all blocks added a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

There are 6 blocks, which are hidden by pressing.
I want to hide after all blocks (`display:none`), added a class.

I tried to do so:

```
$( 'input[type=checkbox]' ).click(function(){
        $('.catalog:has(input:checked)')
            .animate({ opacity: "0.5"},1000)
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(1000);

});



var countCatalog=$('.catalog').length;
    var catalogNone=$('.catalog:hidden').length;

$(function () {
    if ($(countCatalog)==(catalogNone)){
        $('.work').addClass('new__block');
    }
});
```

Hiding works and does not work to add a new block.
I have a bad English, hope you understand me and help me. Thank you.

Comment: `$(countCatalog)` this isn't jQuery object. So you want the checkbox to be hidden if it on click then add class to it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.work').addClass('.new__block');
```

is suppose to be

```
$('.work').addClass('new__block');
```

Comment: Thank you. 
It's just carelessness.
And what about the rest of the?

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite your snippet and explain through the code

```
//Listen on checkbox change event
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function() {
    var $this = $(this), //current changed checbox
        $work = $('.work'), //selector to add new behavior
        $visible = $('input[type="checkbox"]:visible'); //whole visible checkboxes

    //You can change it if you want to lookup check state from DOM
    //$(this).is(':checked')
    //or by attribute
    if ($this.prop('checked')) {
        $this.fadeOut('slow'); //hide it with animation if checked
    }

    //$visible only shows last visible checkboxes before it hides,
    //so it ends at 1 not 0
    if ($visible.length <= 1)
        $work.addClass('new__block'); //add class to $work
});
```

Last, [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nw5cu5m0/)